# How to provide write storage permission in Android 11?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-11

I am trying to store videos in Android Storage Directory However I receive an Error Message
"No such file or directory" Because the storage permission not allowed in Android 11.
I also tried "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" but it didn't work.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9956427?hl=en#zippy=,permitted-uses-of-the-all-files-access-permission

Comment: Please tell full path as it is pretty unclear where you wanna save.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/compatibility